# Disable button in DataGrid based on different column value

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers

I have the following code:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="StringLock" Binding="{Binding StringLock}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CanPressButton">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button>Lock module string</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The StringLock column Background property's color is LightGray if the value of the Text it contains is False.

I want to disable the button in column CanPressButton IF the value of Text is False in the StringLock column.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the full `DataContext` (i.e. row item) at your disposal to trigger on:

```
<Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StringLock}" Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Comment: A little help is required. What books should i read to learn MVVM in WPF? I am working on WPF but with code-behind coding.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I don't recommend books on programming. Also there are questions about learning MVVM on SO.

Comment: Great answer! Works great and is very clean. ;)